# JDBC MATLAB and SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, matlab, jdbc

I see there's already a post on something similar but the solution there didn't work for me. 
I'm trying to use the MATLAB 2017 database app and MSSQL Enterprise so I can import SQL data into MATLAB using SQL syntax. I tried the Mathworks method by creating the two text files. This didn't work as Matlab could not find the .jar and .dll files. 
I then copied these files directly into the Matlab prefdir root and used the add java path and java.lang (see images) to point Matlab towards them. This worked as I know no longer get the cannot find the error. But now I am still getting the "This driver is not configured for ..." error seen in the pic. 
SQL is IP/TCP enabled and the correct port number is used.

Any help would be massively appreciated, guys!

[database app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CXgl.png)    [matlab screen dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0a9b.png)

Comment: Have you tried searching on Google for "matlab sql server driver not configured for integrated authentication"? Specifically this: https://au.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-windows.html

Comment: Hi, yes I stepped through that a few times but no joy. I created the text files also. I'm beginning to think it's something related to MSSQL opposed to matlab?

Comment: Try not using "integrated authentication" and specify SQL User and Password instead (ask your DB admin for that).

Comment: Good suggestion Alex, thanks. I'll try that and let you know how I get on.